# Efficient and salable way to Iterate over a Dataframe and write to text file row by row having huge amount of text data

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I have a large dataframe where each row is containing large amount of text data, I am trying to partition this dataframe on some column in my dataframe i.e. column 11 and then write into multiple files

```
partitioncount = 5
trainingDataFile = 'sometrainingDatFileWithHugeTextDataInEachColumn.tsv'
df = pd.read_table(trainingDataFile, sep='\t', header=None, encoding='utf-8')
# prepare output files and keep them to append the dataframe rows
outputfiles = {}
filename = "C:\Input_Partition"
for i in range(partitioncount):
    outputfiles[i] = open(filename + "_%s.tsv"%(i,), "a")

#Loop through the dataframe and write to buckets/files
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #partition on a hash function
    partition = hash(row[11]) % partitioncount
     outputfiles[partition].write("\t".join([str(num) for num in df.iloc[index].values]) + "\n")
```

This code results with in error : 
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
---> 73             outputfiles[partition].write("\t".join([str(num) for num in df.iloc[index].values]) + "\n")

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.pyc in **getitem**(self, key)
   1326         else:
   1327             key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1328             return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
   1329 
   1330     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.pyc in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1747 
   1748             # validate the location
-> 1749             self._is_valid_integer(key, axis)
   1750 
   1751             return self._get_loc(key, axis=axis)

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.pyc in _is_valid_integer(self, key, axis)
   1636         l = len(ax)
   1637         if key >= l or key < -l:
-> 1638             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
   1639         return True
   1640

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

**What is the most efficient and scalable way to do this i.e. iterate data frame's rows , do some operations on rows (which I am not  showing in code above and irrelevant to the problem in hand) and finally write each row (with large amount of text data) to a text file.**

Appreciate any help!

Comment: `partition = hash(row[11]) % partitioncount` has me a bit baffled. What is this supposed to do?

Comment: its just a hash function to randomly select a bucket/file. it gets the value from column 11 , hash it (to randomize) and then apply modulo 5 , which will give you exactly 5 partitions at max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
filename = r'/path/to/output_{}.csv'

df.groupby(df.iloc[:, 11].map(hash) % partitioncount) \
  .apply(lambda g: g.to_csv(filename.format(g.name), sep='\t', index=False))
```

Comment: This is cool, I learned something new , however, I have to create consistent partitions , meaning, I need to restrict the number of examples per group. i.e. each group can not have more than 1k examples per partition.  With this solution, all examples of a group will go into one partition/file.